# RollOver logic for logs with FileLogTraceListener

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I am trying the following logging behavior:

•Create a new file daily

•When log file exceeds MaxFileSize, create a new file for that day with a new version number.

The first part works fine by setting LogFileCreationSchedule to LogFileCreationScheduleOption.Daily. My code looks something like this.

```
public class MyTraceListener : FileLogTraceListener
 {
    public MyTraceListener (): base()
       {
        this.LogFileCreationSchedule = LogFileCreationScheduleOption.Daily;
       }
 }
```

For the second part i was trying to write my own code to add the counter . But when i was going through the below link in msdn , it is mentioned that it would add an integer to the file name but which doesnt  happening.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.filelogtracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Few lines from the above link::

*Archival functionality. The log files generated by this class are named according to the base name and the date, along with a number to distinguish the log file from successive versions of the log. New log files are created on an as-needed basis.The explicit form of the file name is baseName[-dateStamp][-version].log, where:

◦The baseName part is the fundamental log name, specified by the BaseFileName property.

◦The dateStamp part has the format "YYYY-MM-DD", and it is shown when LogFileCreationSchedule is Daily or Weekly.

**◦If more than one log file is needed with the same baseName and dateStamp, the version part, a positive Integer, is added to the file name.**

Anyone tried using the Daily option and it created the file with number appended to the logfilename (DTM-2015-06-24_1) when it exceeded max size of 5MB which is default value.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

◦If more than one log file is needed with the same baseName and dateStamp, the version part, a positive Integer, is added to the file name.

The above scenario comes when the file is locked by another process.